Fourier coefficients for $f(x) = 3 - \sin(3x)-\dfrac{1}{3}\cos(9x)$.
I am trying to find the fourier coefficients for $f(x) = 3 - \sin(3x)-\dfrac{1}{3}\cos(9x)$
I have understood that the overall period of the function is $\dfrac{2}{3}\pi$, and can due to formulas find that $a_0 = 3$. I also thought I had control while finding $a_n$ and $b_n$ but seems as I am missing something as me and my rough solution do not agree.
To show my thinking; this is how I try to find $a_n$:
$a_n=\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\cdot cos(nx) = \dfrac{1}{\pi}[\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}3 \cos(nx)dx - \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin(3x) \cos(nx)dx-\dfrac{1}{3}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(9x) \cos(nx)dx]$
Then using this the first and second part will disappear due to having the integral of sin and cosinus functions over an entire period, leaving us with the last part: $\dfrac{1}{\pi}\cdot-\dfrac{1}{3}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(9x) \cos(nx)dx$ which due to product to sum identities becomes:
$\dfrac{1}{\pi}\cdot-\dfrac{1}{3}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\dfrac{1}{2}(\cos((9-n)x)+ \cos((9+n)x))dx$
And now I concluded that $a_9=-\dfrac{1}{3}$, but the thing here is that it is not supposed to be $a_9$, it is supposed to be $a_3$(?) Is it something about the period which I am not including in my calculation here? (I believe it is the same problem for calculating $b_n$ so not including that calculation. Grateful for help!

First ask yourself what a Fourier series looks like, then look at your function. Now simply write down the Fourier coefficients, no integrals required.

@paul Don't have that much experience with fourier series yet, so even though i know how it looks i dont understand how i can conclude that it is a_3 and b_1? How can i spot these n values - and how do i spot the exact solutions?

Isn’t $f(x)$ already a Fourier series?

If $T=\frac{2\pi}{3}$ then the fundamental frequency is $\omega_0 = \frac{2\pi}{T} =3$. Can you go from there?

There's two ways to do this. One is to determine the Fourier coefficients by inspection, i.e., by understanding what a Fourier series looks like and seeing what the coefficients have to be. (That's the fast way.) The other is to determine them via integration. That's the slow way, and the only practical reason to use that method is if the former isn't possible. (For instance, the Fourier coefficients of a square wave can't be read off by inspection.)

Okay, now i can spot the solutions, but I still no not understand which mistakes i make using the integration method - because if i need it i do not want to perform it wrong...
